# Read csv from S3 in Laravel?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-4

I have a csv file which already uploaded in S3 server. May I know how could I load or read the file data that downloaded from S3?

Code

```
        $path = Input::get('filename');
        $s3 = new S3Client(Config::get('image'));
        $result = $s3->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => Config::get('image.bucket'),
            'Key'    => Config::get('node.subdomain') . '/upload/' . $path,
        ));

        $r = fopen($result['Body'], 'a');

        Debugbar::addMessage($result,"download");
```

Now I'm getting `failed to open stream: Invalid argument`

Comment: `fopen(path` should be `fopen($path` and I don't know that you'll be able to append to a bucket but I think what you're looking for is http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: I updated my code after I read the AWS s3 documentation about how to get the object from S3. Now I retrieved a list of object from S3 but I'm not sure how to load it.

Comment: you are getting an object, not a stream.  Try : `$csv = (string) $result['Body']`; ... ps, you can get streams from the S3 client, if you insist, look for it.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Could you provide an example to get streams from the S3 client?I think it will one of solution to get larger file from S3.

Answer (score 1):

There are two pieces at play.

1. Your project file system config.
2. Parsing the lines of csv.

PROJECT/config/filesystems.php

```
<?php return [...
'disks' => [
...
    'myS3drive' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key'    => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ]
    ...]
...
```

Then you can use something like this elsewhere in your project.

```
$csv = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('s3')->get('myDataFile.csv');
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $csv) as $line){
    $data = str_getcsv($line);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can save your files locally and then read them in with the following:

```
library(aws.s3) # to connect to s3 buckets
library(tidyverse) # for the pipes
library(data.table) # for the fread()

data <- 
  save_object("s3://myBucketName/directoryName/fileName.csv") %>%
  fread()
```

If you don't want to fill your working directory with a copy of every csv you load, then this is a better alternative:

```
data <- 
  save_object("s3://myBucketName/directoryName/fileName.csv",
              file = tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
             ) %>%
  fread()
```

And if you are curious about where the tempfile is positioned, then  `Sys.getenv()` can give some insight - see `TMPDIR` `TEMP` or `TMP`. More information can be found in [the Base R tempfile docs.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/tempfile).